# Freezing rows and columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, multiple-columns, rows, ssrs-2012, freeze

I need to freeze my row headers and the first three columns in my SSRS report. I don't have a column group. In th tablix properties, I have checked the **Keep header visible while scrolling** option. When I scroll down, I am having no issues the rows headers are visible.

[image]

But when I scroll right, this is how my report looks like:

[image]

I want to see the row headers for the first three columns that have been freezed as well.

Can anyone suggest how do I go about doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check both Row Headers and Column Headers **Keep header visibile while scrolling**

Comment: no that is not working as i have got no column groups

Comment: Is it a matrix or a table?

Comment: it is a matrix. I have set the FixedData option for static groups to True, even then it is not working

Comment: This worked out... There was some other issue with the design

Comment: @YousufSultan how did you solve your problem?